# Mac Screen - red discoloration

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

At random times, there is a red discoloration in the corner of my screen that varies in size from nonexistant to stretching across the right edge. It is similar to the following thread except that thread mentions the whole screen and my issue only covers a single corner:
[MacBook Pro display suddenly has a very faint warm/pink tint](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321863/macbook-pro-display-suddenly-has-a-very-faint-warm-pink-tint)

A couple of observations I noticed was that when you take a screenshot, the discoloration is not in the screen shot. When I physically press the cloud with my finger, it goes away for a short time but comes back.

Does anyone know what is going on and what to do about it?

Edit: [image]
This photo was taken yesterday. As of now, there is no red tint on my screen.

Comment: The screen may have been physically damaged by the laptop falling on that corner. This may have been recent, but perhaps at some time in the past: the problem can appear well after the actual hit. This is evidenced by the observation that the discoloration is visibly altered by contact with the screen. If it were a processor/graphics card/ribbon-cable problem, you wouldn't be able to have an effect on the discoloration. What model of Macbook?

Comment: Take a photo of the screen and also a screenshot. See if it happens on both. Post here so we can see.

Comment: Like @IconDaemon said, it is likely physical damage or a part going bad, either way you can just ignore it, have it repaired (probably replacing the screen) or use an external monitor. But with a laptop the latter is not likely to be a good choice...

Comment: OP indicates a screenshot does not show the discoloration.